# Grant permissions to user for backup/restore in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-backups

Can anyone tell me what permissions must i give to a user inside SQL Server 2005 so that this user can backup and restore a database without given him sysadmin server role ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a db_backupoperator fixed database role in 2005 that should meet your requirements. See description here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189612(v=sql.90).aspx

```
USE YourDatabase
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator', 'YourUser'
GO
```

Comment: I think the user also needs to be the database owner to do the restore.

Comment: And by owner, I mean owner, not db_owner role.  Only one login can be that, so it has some limits.